# How to run a function on multiple events?

Tags: javascript

I want to run a function that I have when two variables have triggered events. I have tried multiple methods but nothing works. Is it possible?

Here is what I have tried to give you further clarification if needed:

```js
function run(arg) {
  ...
}
let e = false
event1.on('event', pass => { if (e) { run(pass) } else { e = true } })
event2.on('event', pass => { if (e) { run(pass) } else { e = true } })
```

```js
function run(arg) {
  ...
}
[event1, event2].on('event', pass => { run(pass) } )
```

```js
function run(arg) {
  ...
}
(event1 && event2).on('event', pass => { run(pass) } )
```

So far nothing has worked. I only want the function to run when *BOTH* of the events are triggered. How could I do this?

Comment: Are you working on framework or just javascript? Also, which events?

Comment: Im using node, this is a custom event in one of my classes

Comment: I guess describing your goal and those events will help us to help you.

Comment: It runs when it reads three lines that match a certain regular expressions and takes them all in.

Answer (score 0):

First create an array, on each event trigger add to the array index that the event has indeed been triggered.

After this is done, just check if the array has both events inside, then start run function.

```
var array = [];
function event1(){
  array.push("event1");
}
function event2(){
  array.push("event2");
}


//Check if array have 2 events triggered
if(array.some(val => val === "event1") && array.some(val => val === "event2")){
  run(pass);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this did not work but I was able to fix my issue with `await` and part of this. Thanks for your time!